# Why use empty loop for datareader?

Tags: c#, sql

I'm making a n-tier web application, and created a method to add data to a specific database. My question is when making a connection to the database and executing the query, why is there a loop for the DataReader object with nothing in it. Here is my method:

```
while (myReader.Read())
{

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DataReader` doesn't fetch data at once, it only starts reading a record when you call the `Read` method. Actually, the read method advances the `SqlDataReader` to the next record so it returns `true` if there are more rows; otherwise `false`.

```
while(dataReader.Read()) // true if there are more rows; otherwise false.
{
    // code to run
}
```

You can read about it here in [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: Okay so does that mean when I am adding to my database that while loop will just add to the last record of the database then add the entry?

Comment: No, the current `DataReader` is associated with a `SqlConnection` that had opened a `Transaction` already. It only returns data that exist on the time of calling `ExecuteDataReader`.

Comment: Since I am adding to the database, why wouldn't I be able to remove this code? If it is just getting data already inside the database?

Comment: Don't use a `DataReader` to write data to the database. The clue is in the name.

Comment: I was just watching a tutorial and saw this part in it and wondered why as I thought it was redundant.

Comment: Why don't you try commenting it out and see what happens? I've never tried to insert with a Reader, but clearly it will work even though the code looks a little odd, as you have shown. I suspect it requires the `dataReader.Read()` statement as the SQL won't actually be run until this call. An `INSERT` can return data to a reader - normally a count of the affected rows assuming `NOCOUNT` has not been set. In the example this is ignored, which is why it's clearer to use a writer or a non-query.

Answer (score 0):

myReader.Read() true if there are more rows; otherwise false.

Refer : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read?view=netframework-4.8